# Share a link badges

Tags: support

I do not quite understand how the "share a link" badges work.

Is the idea that you post the URL to some other web site and people click on it? But then how they know you posted the URL?

Share the link where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the URL from clicking on <kbd>share</kbd> underneath the post, instead of the URL in your address bar.

The link that provided by the <kbd>share</kbd> button has your user number encoded into it.

For example, the URL for this question, from me pressing the <kbd>share</kbd> button, is:

```
http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/q/2217/2435
```

The ID number of this question is 2217, and my user ID is 2435. If you were to click on the <kbd>share</kbd> button, your user ID would be used instead.

Stack Exchange counts the number of times somebody has been directed to the site from one of those links for the link-related badges.

Comment: fascinating, thanks very much

Comment: One thing to add: Only visits from outside the SE network count towards the share badges.